# jQuery - How do I Move a closing tag in my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am looking for a way to move just a closing form tag  using jQuery.

Currently the HTML looks something like this:

```
<form class="myform">
  <input class="text_field" id="profile_nickname" name="profile[nickname]" size="30" type="text" value="" data-validate="true">
</form>
<div class="form-action">
  <submit class="x">
</div>
```

Because the submit tag is outside of the form, the submit button doesn't work.

I want to say something like:

```
$(".myform").remove('</form>')
$('</form>').appendTo($('.form-action'))
```

This of course does not work. Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Any specific reason why you are having the submit tag outside the form tags ?

Comment: You don't need jQuery to do this - you need a text editor!

Comment: Its just one of those situations where I dont have access to the code that creates the form, but I can write some javascript to fix the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) does not work like string concatenation where you can chop one slice and paste it somewhere else... you need to move the dom elements

```
$('.form-action').appendTo('.myform')
```

Comment: Under most circumstances that would work, but in this case the code put in the question was an example designed for simplicity. I am specifically looking for a way to move the placement of a closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can use click event to sent out the form

```
$(".form-action").click(submitForm);

function submitForm(){
$(".myform").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can clone the old object,append the new one to "form",and hide the old one.

```
var $new = $('.form-action').clone();
$('.form-action').hide();
$new.show();
$new.appendTo('.myform');
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels really wrong, but I know what its like to work under bad conditions with a hateful content management system... So here it goes...

***If there is really no other way around it*** you can reset the HTML content with .[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKxTj/1/)**

```
$('body').html(
    '<form class="myform">' +
    '<input class="text_field" id="profile_nickname" name="profile[nickname]" size="30" type="text" value="" data-validate="true">' +
    '<div class="form-action">' +
    ' <submit class="x">' +
    '</div></form>');
```

This is an ugly way to do it, but if you're backed into a corner it will work.